# One analytic solution of Schwarzschild metrics and Maxwell's equations in this curved space-time

Tags: observational-astronomy, general-relativity

One analytic solution (ref. 1) in projected local orthonormal tetrad e_lambda^, (^ is not power mark in this case)

B_theta^ = (1/r^3)*mu*sin(theta)*[ 6x^3*(1-x^(-1))^(1/2)*ln(1-x^(-1))+6*x^2*(1-0.5*x^(-1))/(1-x^(-1))^(1/2) ],

B_r^ = (1/r^3)*2*mu*cos(theta)*[ -3x^3*ln(1-x^(-1))-3x^2*(1+0.5x^(-1)) ], x = r/(2*M).

(Conversion to SI units M -> M*G/c^2, mu -> mu0/(4*Pi)*mu, mu now Am^2 in SI units, mu0 = 4*Pi*10^(-7)*m*kg*s^(-2)*A^(-2) in SI units)

Maple 9 plot would give for neutron star (near surface, max limit about neutron star (magnetar here) calculation?)

max B_theta^ = about 1.2*10^13*T (equator, theta=Pi/2), max B_r^ = about 5.2*10^12*T (pole, theta=0),

Maple 9 plot would give for neutron star (near surface, min limit calculation ?)

max B_theta^ = about 7.45*10^9*T (equator; theta=Pi/2), max B_r^ = about 3.25*10^9*T (pole, theta=0).

I have used following in my calculation: M = 1.5*M_Sun = 2.98275*10^30*kg,(I don't remember reference of this), c = 2.99792488*10^8*m*s^(-1), G = 6.6743*10^(-11)**m^3*kg^(-1)*s^(-2), mu = 1.6*10^32*gauss*cm^3 = 1.6*10^29*A*m^2, (= magnetar magnetic moment for max neutron star magnetic moment, I don't remember reference of this),

(observed values (Ref.2) for magnetic moments are mu = about range (10^29->10^32)*gauss*cm^3 = (10^26->10^29)*A*m^2).

mu0 = 4*Pi*10^(-7)*m*kg*s^(-2)*A^(-2), SI-units of B are [B] = kg*s^(-2)*A^(-1) = T = Tesla.

If I calculate with mu = 10^29*A*m^2 as observed max for neutron stars I get from Maple 9 plots (near surface):

max B_theta^ = about 7.45*10^12*T (equator, theta = Pi/2), max B_r^ = about 3.25*10^12*T (pole, theta = 0).

Observed values of magnetic moments of neutron stars are from Ref.2

Please take a look these analytic formulae and the Ref.1,

(this article was 22.2.2024 in sci.physics.relativity, but Google Groups ended and stopped 22.2.2024, all old postings are still readable after 22.2.2024, for example mine use search term "Hannu Poropudas".)

Q1. Please give me comments about how usable these analytic formulae are ?

Q2. Maple 9 plots given about B_theta^, B_r^ numbers: What is possible range of M ? and what is possible range of magnetic moment of neutron star ?

Q3. Max ranges observed for neutron stars (M=1.5M_Sun): max B_theta^ = about 7.45*10^9*T -> 7.45*10^12*T (equator, theta=Pi/2), max B_r^ = about 3.25*10^9*T -> 3.25*10^12*T (pole, theta=0) ?

Reference 1.

Wasserman Ira and Shapiro Stuart L., 1983. Masses, radii, and magnetic fields of pulsating X-ray sources: Is the "Standard" Model self-consistent ? The Astrophysical Journal, 265: 1036-1046, February 15. (G=1, c=1 units, c.g.s units, electromagnetic units not SI units).

Reference 2.

Ghosh P. and Lamb F. K. 1979. Accretion by rotating magnetic neutron stars. II. Radial and vertical structure of the transition zone in disk accretion. The Astrophysical Journal, 232:259-276, 1979 August 15, page 273.

Comment: Hello Hannu.  Please not that this site has TeX syntax enabled so you can write maths like  $B_\theta$ with dollar signs

Comment: I'am sorry but I have not TeX available at the moment.

Comment: No, this site has TeX available.  You just need to retype your maths in TeX format.  At the moment it is almost illegible

Comment: I'am sorry, but it has been about 18 years when I used LaTex last time. So I cannot edit so at the moment.

Comment: This question could probably do with some editing. Of your three questions, Q1 seems to be overly broad and general with no possible "best" or "correct" answer.  Q2 seems answerable,  Q3 doesn't appear to be a question

Comment: "18 years..."  Time to learn again.  It's up to you.  But at the moment the notation is almost illegible.  So do you want answers or not?

Comment: Yes, but it will take little longer time than at the moment?

Comment: The question does not start with a sentence I understand. It's unclear to me where single formula start and end. The plots referred to are not shown. Symbols not explained. Links to references work on the internet. Why should we search on google groups for your name instead of you linking to whatever further information might be required to understand your question or improving the legibility in the first place?

Comment: Please look "edit" version where I have put multiplication mark (*)  in correct places.

Comment: I found with Google two partial answers to Q2 question: I. Typically, astronomers consider the mass of a neutron star to range from 1.4 to 2.9 solar masses. Then, if the collapsed core has more than three solar masses it becomes a black hole. II. The mass of a neutron star can vary, but most neutron stas have a mass ranging from about 1.4 to 2.1 times the mass of the Sun. This range is known as the "Chandrasekhar limit" and represents the maximum mass at which a white dwarf star can remain stable before collapsing into a neutron star.

Comment: Putting in the * has just made things worse, since the * is used in markdown for italics.  There is a right way to format maths, and you are not doing it the right way. You say ^ is not power mark.... so what is it?  I've voted to close, as I don't think this question can be answered in this state.

Comment: It’s very inconvenient to read, I suggest replacing the text of the formulas with screenshots from Maple, what do you think?

Comment: I don't want to waste my time to this my trying to convert my ASCII text to LaTEX form.

Comment: About those Maple 9 plots: I used in all plotting ranges from r = 0 to about 1000*(2*M*G/c^2). Range from 0 to (2*M*G/c^2) Maple 9 gives complex numbers, so

Answer (score 0):

About those Maple 9 plots: I used in all plotting ranges from r = 0 to about 1000*(2*M*G/c^2). Range from r = 0 to (2*M*G/c^2) Maple 9 gives complex numbers, so this range is not plotted. Maple 9 plots then near singularity r = (2*M*G/c^2) to about 1000*(2*M*G/c^2)  deeply decreasing hyperbola like curve, which started about those maximum values which numbers I gave to B_theta^ and B_r^. About Q2. Range for mass of neutron stars is about 1.4*M_Sun to about 2.9*M_Sun and range for magnetic dipole moments for observed neutron stars is 10^26*A*m^2 to 10^29*A*m^2 in SI-units.